# Connect gmail api with username and password

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, gmail-api

While I am trying to use Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2

I give it a secret key login,

json:

```
"installed": {
    "client_id": "ClientId",
    "project_id": "project_id",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "client_secret",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost" ]
```

and then it requested login with my Gmail account, after success login
it grand me access token for 6 hours:

json:

```
{
  "access_token": "access_token key",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "1/kRTvuCKTndK-P6wueRd7WJYXXWcS1du8MTOnp6VKXKw",
  "scope": "https://mail.google.com/",
  "Issued": "2019-01-19T18:45:32.016+02:00",
  "IssuedUtc": "2019-01-19T16:45:32.016Z"
}
```

but I want it to be Automatic without login account,

How could I do it?

I don't care if the Credential be plain text in the code (it's just a test).

Comment: Try using service account, this will help you impersonate and automatically authorize your app without logging in. Check this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), this will help you delegate domain-wide authority to the service account.